# Color a column by another column's value

Tags: r, gt

I would like to create a gt table where I display numeric values from two columns together in a single cell, but color the cells based on just one of the column's values.

For example using the `ToothGrowth` example data I'd like to put the `len` and `dose` columns together in a single cell but color the cell backgrounds by the value of `dose`.

I tried to manually create a vector of colors to color the `len_dose` column but this does not work because it seems like it is reapplying the color vector to each different level of `len_dose`, not `dose`. I guess you could manually format the cells with `tab_style()` but that seems inefficient and does not give you the nice feature where the text color changes to maximize contrast with background. I don't know an efficient way to do this.

What I tried:

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(glue)

# Manually map dose to color
dose_colors <- col_numeric(palette = 'Reds', domain = range(ToothGrowth$dose))(ToothGrowth$dose)

ToothGrowth %>%
  mutate(len_dose = glue('{len}: ({dose})')) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = 'supp') %>%
  cols_hide(c(len, dose)) %>%
  data_color(len_dose, colors = dose_colors)
```

Output (not good because not colored by dose):

[image]

Comment: This has now been implemented in gt - see https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/1103 - so the best solution is just to use their new `data_color()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update Feb 2023

The option to color based on another column has now been added to the `gt` package - `data_color()` has gained a `taregt_columns` argument. So this has become much simpler:

```r
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

ToothGrowth %>%
  mutate(len_dose = glue('{len}: ({dose})')) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = 'supp') %>%
  cols_hide(c(len, dose)) %>%
  data_color(columns = "dose", target_columns = "len_dose",
             palette = "ggsci::green_material")
```

---

### Outdated

I faced the same issue and adjusted the gt::data_color function to accept separate source and target columns - with that, the following should work to produce your desired output.

```r
# Distinguish SOURCE_columns and TARGET_columns

my_data_color <- function (data, SOURCE_columns, TARGET_columns, colors, alpha = NULL, apply_to = c("fill", 
                                                                                                    "text"), autocolor_text = TRUE) 
{
  stop_if_not_gt(data = data)
  apply_to <- match.arg(apply_to)
  colors <- rlang::enquo(colors)
  data_tbl <- dt_data_get(data = data)
  colors <- rlang::eval_tidy(colors, data_tbl)
  resolved_source_columns <- resolve_cols_c(expr = {
    {
      SOURCE_columns
    }
  }, data = data)
  resolved_target_columns <- resolve_cols_c(expr = {
    {
      TARGET_columns
    }
  }, data = data)
  rows <- seq_len(nrow(data_tbl))
  data_color_styles_tbl <- dplyr::tibble(locname = character(0), 
                                         grpname = character(0), colname = character(0), locnum = numeric(0), 
                                         rownum = integer(0), colnum = integer(0), styles = list())
  for (i in seq_along(resolved_source_columns)) {
    data_vals <- data_tbl[[resolved_source_columns[i]]][rows]
    if (inherits(colors, "character")) {
      if (is.numeric(data_vals)) {
        color_fn <- scales::col_numeric(palette = colors, 
                                        domain = data_vals, alpha = TRUE)
      }
      else if (is.character(data_vals) || is.factor(data_vals)) {
        if (length(colors) > 1) {
          nlvl <- if (is.factor(data_vals)) {
            nlevels(data_vals)
          }
          else {
            nlevels(factor(data_vals))
          }
          if (length(colors) > nlvl) {
            colors <- colors[seq_len(nlvl)]
          }
        }
        color_fn <- scales::col_factor(palette = colors, 
                                       domain = data_vals, alpha = TRUE)
      }
      else {
        cli::cli_abort("Don't know how to map colors to a column of class {class(data_vals)[1]}.")
      }
    }
    else if (inherits(colors, "function")) {
      color_fn <- colors
    }
    else {
      cli::cli_abort("The `colors` arg must be either a character vector of colors or a function.")
    }
    color_fn <- rlang::eval_tidy(color_fn, data_tbl)
    color_vals <- color_fn(data_vals)
    color_vals <- html_color(colors = color_vals, alpha = alpha)
    color_styles <- switch(apply_to, fill = lapply(color_vals, 
                                                   FUN = function(x) cell_fill(color = x)), text = lapply(color_vals, 
                                                                                                          FUN = function(x) cell_text(color = x)))
    data_color_styles_tbl <- dplyr::bind_rows(data_color_styles_tbl, 
                                              generate_data_color_styles_tbl(column = resolved_target_columns[i], rows = rows, 
                                                                             color_styles = color_styles))
    if (apply_to == "fill" && autocolor_text) {
      color_vals <- ideal_fgnd_color(bgnd_color = color_vals)
      color_styles <- lapply(color_vals, FUN = function(x) cell_text(color = x))
      data_color_styles_tbl <- dplyr::bind_rows(data_color_styles_tbl, 
                                                generate_data_color_styles_tbl(column = resolved_target_columns[i], 
                                                                               rows = rows, color_styles = color_styles))
    }
  }
  dt_styles_set(data = data, styles = dplyr::bind_rows(dt_styles_get(data = data), 
                                                       data_color_styles_tbl))
}


# Add function into gt namespace (so that internal gt functions can be called)
library(gt)
tmpfun <- get("data_color", envir = asNamespace("gt"))
environment(my_data_color) <- environment(tmpfun)

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(glue)

# Map dose to color
ToothGrowth %>%
  mutate(len_dose = glue('{len}: ({dose})')) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = 'supp') %>%
  cols_hide(c(len, dose)) %>%
  my_data_color(SOURCE_columns = "dose", TARGET_columns = "len_dose", 
             colors = scales::col_numeric(palette = c("red", "green"), domain = c(min(ToothGrowth$dose), max(ToothGrowth$dose))))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is great, you should consider submitting a pull request to gt

Comment: Thanks! I suggested this to gt, but I don't think it is quite in line with their interface ...

Comment: This has now been implemented in gt - see https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/1103 - so the best solution is just to use their new `data_color()` function.

Comment: thank you for letting me & everyone know! Would you consider updating this accepted answer to reflect the new version of gt's `data_color()`?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you found a solution to this yet but here is what I did:

- If you use `tab_style()` you don't need to try and create the vector of colors and can instead set the background color you want based on the `dose` column. If you want to color values differently based on `dose`, in addition to what I've colored here, then create another `tab_style()` for the desired value.

  ```
  library(gt)
   library(dplyr)
   library(scales)
   library(glue)

   ToothGrowth %>%
     mutate(len_dose = glue('{len}: ({dose})')) %>%
     gt(rowname_col = 'supp') %>%
     tab_style(
       style = cell_fill(color = "palegreen"),
       location = cells_body(
         columns = len_dose,
         rows = dose >= 1.0
       )
     ) %>%
     cols_hide(c(len, dose))
  ```

[image]

Comment: This looks great! The only disappointing thing is I guess you still need to call `tab_style` multiple times if you want to have more than two different background values. With this solution, there's still no way to do it with a continuous value as you can with `data_color`, correct?

Comment: You could do use `&` or `|` like this `ToothGrowth %>%
  mutate(len_dose = glue('{len}: ({dose})')) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = 'supp') %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "palegreen"),
    location = cells_body(
      columns = len_dose,
      rows = dose > 1.0 | dose < 1.0
    )
  ) %>%
  cols_hide(c(len, dose))`

Comment: But that would still require a different call to `tab_style` for each additional background color you wanted to add, right? As I stated in the original question, adding colors one at a time with `tab_style` is not really efficient if you have a continuous-valued column that you want to use to color a different column. So I will hold off on accepting your answer for now, thanks again for your help.